# Any security risk with raising client_max_body_size nginx?

Tags: webserver, nginx

i was wondering if there is any securitiy risk involved with raising the client_max_body_size in nginx from 1MB to 20GB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `client_max_body_size` to 20 GB is, obviously, not reasonable and I wonder why you would allow (users?, yourself?) to upload such very huge files.

`client_max_body_size` governs the corresponding HTTP Header parameter. As a security good practice, we must always limit the header and message body to a minimal reasonable length. Why ? 20 GB is so huge that you put your server in the same scenario as by [2013 when Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/) allowed users to use a very long password forcing Django (rather the server where it is hosted) to perform very expensive hash calculations leading, as you may guess, to  a [denial-of-service](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Denial_of_Service) attack against the whole Django's authentication framework.

This is said, there are other things you need to think about if you increase too much the size of `client_max_body_size`. For instance, how will you set `keepalive_timeout` parameter ? How could you calculate it based on the fact that `client_max_body_size` is set to 20 GB ? May be 20 seconds ? 20 minutes ? Two hours ? Same question concerns `client_header_timeout` and `client_body_timeout`  that set, respectiely, set the maximum amount of time Nginx will wait around on the client to specify a request header or ask for an object to be served.

Comment: I have a Reverse proxy and behind that there is a server with owncloud on, the reverse proxy was putting a limit where i could only upload 1 mb. to my Owncloud server, and that was the only solution i could come up with.

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes That is good. And remember to think about security in terms of [layered defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_security)

Comment: so it wont be a problem ? is that what you mean?

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes By *good* I mean it is *better* you expose your proxy rather than your main servers. That is all. But I said you have to think in terms of **layered security**, I mean what I outlined through my answer concerning your main server is applicable to your proxy server too because this late one is not DDoS safe by default.